# Microsoft Access 2010 break up text

Tags: ms-access, vba, calculated-columns, calculated-field

I have tried a couple of other solutions suggested to break up a text field but I get an error #Type!.  This is supposed to indicate that the value I am looking for does not exist in the field I am looking up but it does.  I want to create a new column called Title that only has the Title and then I will create a second column with the Company.  The Title and company are separated by an underscore.  I want to break up the text based on the underscore.  I tried the following for the title column

```
Left([Title with Company],InStr([Title with Company],"_",-1))
```

This gives me the #type! error.  How can I make two columns one with only the Title and then a second only with the Company using the underscore as the separating character in the Title with Company column?

In Excel I got this to work for the Title

```
LEFT(A4,FIND("_",A4&"_")-1)
```

and this to work for the company

```
RIGHT(A4,LEN(A4)-FIND("_",A4))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have a misplaced parenthesis:

```
Left([Title with Company], InStr([Title with Company],"_") - 1)
```

The INSTR should end after the search unless you are supplying the Compare type.

```
InStr([start, ]string1, string2[, compare])
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445031(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: <Okay, after looking at the link I got this to work for finding the part before the underscore>
`Left([Title with Company],InStr(1,[Title with Company],"_")-1)`
<br/>

Now I have to figure out how to get it to fine the text after the underscore.

Comment: That would be similar logic but using MID:
MID([Title with Company], InStr([Title with Company], "_") - 1, LEN([Title with Company])
Or you could use Right like your example: RIGHT(A4,LEN(A4) - InStr(A4, "_"))

Answer (score 0):

To extract the text after the underscore I got this to work

```
Right(Trim([Title with Company]),Len(Trim([Title with Company]))-InStr(1,[Title with Company],"_"))
```

To extract the text before the underscore I got this to work

```
Left([Title with Company],InStr(1,[Title with Company],"_")-1)
```